# Bank Automation Teller Machine (ATM) use-case diagram, is "Login" is a "use-case"

Tags: uml, use-case

This is a simple ATM use-case diagram:
I think it missed something like Login (authentication) and Print (after Transfer, Withdraw... we will be asked for selecting print bill or not). So are they use-case?
[image: ATM use-case diagram]

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137547/use-case-diagram-log-on-use-case?rq=1

Comment: Voting -1. Read the complete article http://www.uml-diagrams.org/bank-atm-uml-use-case-diagram-example.html?context=uc-examples including chapter "Bank ATM Transactions and Customer Authentication Use Cases Example". It is matter of the **level of detail**

Comment: Right, sorry for my mistake, The "login" is "customer authenticate", which is a sub-level usecase, thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When trying to decide if a certain piece of behavior should be a use case you should look to the "observable result" for the main actor. Does "login" yield such a result?

It depends on the system you are developing, the complexity of the authentication system etc. It might be a mere step in the use case scenario or it might become a (secondary) use case.

Another tool I teach my students is the BOSS test.
You have to ask yourself:

> Will my boss be happy when I  100 times today?

Usually usecases like "Login" fail the BOSS test. Things like "Create Order" or "Pay Invoice" usually pass the BOSS test.

But again whether or not to make a use case depends on your methodology (granularity of your use cases), on your system, and on the complexity. There is no YES/NO answer.

Answer (score 1):

No absolutely not. "Login" and "Print" are not usecases of ATM. User must by identified before use of ATM services as describe usecase diagram you provide. But, user does not use ATM for LOGIN service. It is not meaningful service. Print is not a UseCase as well. Print is one of step of processes within some of usecases of ATM.

Your UseCase diagram is correct.

Comment: I think it really depends on whether the ATM system is responsible for user authentication or not.  IMO, that's a requirement that has to be gathered, not an assertion that is always false.

Comment: ATM is always responsible for user authentication. But it is not service provided to user at all.

Comment: I take your point.  However, the process of getting the user's card input and PIN number could be construed as an authentication process with which the user interacts.  Therefore, it is important to define what "authentication" is before determining whether it is a use case in a user system or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `Login` is a use case. If `Login` doesn't happen, then none of the other use cases can happen.

Comment: But doesn't that make "Login" a mere component of the other use cases? (I grant you that I have logged in to an ATM for the sole purpose of checking that the card still works)

Comment: `Login` is a _necessary_ component of the other use cases, and must be implemented. Try using an ATM that has no `Login` function!

Comment: Login isn't a component of the other use cases, or the user would have to log in when entering each of them.  If it is to be stated as a use case, it should be a separate one.

Answer (score 0):

A use-case is a process where an actor interacts with the system. Now map this with Login. Login is a user authentication process where the customer inputs the card and PIN. Then the system carries out the authentication. So this is by all means a use-case.